# Datatable.addrow Throws System.Data.EvaluateException

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I've search online and what I've seen is that this usually throws when there's a filter string datatype mismatch but I've just been adding a new row to a datatable.

```
var newInvoiceDetailRow = _Invoicing_DataSet.Sales_InvoiceListDetails.NewSales_InvoiceListDetailsRow();


                newInvoiceDetailRow.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                newInvoiceDetailRow.Discount = 0;
                newInvoiceDetailRow.InvoiceListID = newInvoiceRow.ID;
                newInvoiceDetailRow.LineTotal = 0;
                newInvoiceDetailRow.OrderCode = row.OrderCode.ToString();
                newInvoiceDetailRow.OrderListDetailID = row.ID;
                newInvoiceDetailRow.PackagingQuantity = row.PackagingQuantity;
                newInvoiceDetailRow.PiecesPerPackaging = row.Pieces_Per_Packaging;
                newInvoiceDetailRow.ProductPrice = row.Price;
                newInvoiceDetailRow.Product_Code = row.Product_Code.ToString();
                newInvoiceDetailRow.Product_Name = row.Product_Name.ToString();
                newInvoiceDetailRow.Quantity = row.Quantity;
                newInvoiceDetailRow.UnitUsed = row.UnitUsed;
                newInvoiceDetailRow.UpdatedBy = CreatingUser.ToString();
                newInvoiceDetailRow.Seq = seq;

                _Invoicing_DataSet.Sales_InvoiceListDetails.AddSales_InvoiceListDetailsRow(newInvoiceDetailRow);
```

```
System.Data.EvaluateException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232032
  Message=Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.BinaryNode.BinaryCompare(Object vLeft, Object vRight, StorageType resultType, Int32 op, CompareInfo comparer)
       at System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left, ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[] recordNos)
       at System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version)
       at System.Data.DataExpression.Invoke(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version)
       at System.Data.Index.AcceptRecord(Int32 record, IFilter filter)
       at System.Data.Index.ApplyChangeAction(Int32 record, Int32 action, Int32 changeRecord)
       at System.Data.Index.RecordStateChanged(Int32 record, DataViewRowState oldState, DataViewRowState newState)
       at System.Data.DataTable.RecordStateChanged(Int32 record1, DataViewRowState oldState1, DataViewRowState newState1, Int32 record2, DataViewRowState oldState2, DataViewRowState newState2)
       at System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(DataRow row, Int32 proposedRecord, DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Boolean suppressEnsurePropertyChanged, Int32 position, Boolean fireEvent, Exception& deferredException)
       at System.Data.DataTable.InsertRow(DataRow row, Int64 proposedID, Int32 pos, Boolean fireEvent)
       at System.Data.DataRowCollection.Add(DataRow row)
       at Invoicing._Invoicing_DataSet.Sales_InvoiceListDetailsDataTable.AddSales_InvoiceListDetailsRow(Sales_InvoiceListDetailsRow row)
```

I've been at it for some time now.
Not sure what the problem is.
Would appreciate any help

Comment: `newInvoiceDetailRow.OrderCode = row.OrderCode.ToString();` ?

Comment: I've already set it to string and its still throwing the error. 
I've also tried to explicitly define the values and it still throws the error. ie.
                    newInvoiceDetailRow.PackagingQuantity = 0;
                    newInvoiceDetailRow.PiecesPerPackaging = 0;
                    newInvoiceDetailRow.ProductPrice = 0;
                    newInvoiceDetailRow.Product_Code = "";
                    newInvoiceDetailRow.Product_Name = "";

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

An existing Binding source had a filter that would cause the exception. When the row was added to the datatable the binding source having a wrong filter compares the string to the int.

this confused me since the line throwing the error was the add row.